# Dealing with lower- and upper-bound truncated data with Tweedie distribution through glmmTMB

Tags: fitting, nested-data, glmmtmb, tweedie-distribution

I'm working with intensive longitudinal data with observations nested within persons via glmmTMB with a random effect of person. My outcome is negative emotion, which was computed by taking the mean of four discrete emotions (e.g., mad, sad) at the observation level, all of which were reported on a 0-100 sliding scale. The outcome is heavily zero-inflated, so as part of our pre-registration we outlined a plan for testing various distributions via the DHARMa package.

Histogram of the raw data (i.e., no accounting for clustering) is below. I have ~2200 observations nested within ~115 individuals.

[image]

I've tested poisson, negative binomial, gamma, hurdle and tweedie distributions (with and without zero-inflation) and found that the tweedie distribution fit the data best (and aligns with the nature of our outcome and theoretical model, which doesn't assume a two-process data generation). However, inspection of the residuals still indicates some clustering, particularly at the low and high values of x. DHARMa residual plots below. I am wondering if this pattern is likely to result from the boundedness of our original emotion variable, and if there are any ways we can address this model mis-fit via our model specification. My colleagues and I don't have any hypotheses about possible quadratic effects (although I tested a couple) or missing variable dependency here. Looking at the residuals in the plot below, there is clearly still some clustering, but I'm not sure if it's enough to be a concern.

Here is the final model with the tweedie distribution. Predictors: w_emotion is peak negative emotion (mirrors the outcome, but in response to the worst interaction they had since the last sampling moment); connectednessPM/PMC is centered social connectedness, and peers is a binary 0/1 variable indicating whether the person was with peers (vs. parents/others) at the sampling occasion, peersPM20 is the person-mean of percent of occasions with peers across the sampling period, centered on the grand mean, and Study_Day is the effect of time:

```
tweediefullModel <-glmmTMB(m_emotion ~ w_emotion + scale(connectednessPM)*peers + scale(connectednessPMC)*peers +
                      scale(connectednessPM)*peersPM20 + scale(connectednessPMC)*peersPM20 + 
                      Study_Day + (1|ID_Num), family = "tweedie"(link='log'), data = full10)
```

And here's the DHARMa residual plot:
[image]

I am fairly new to the specifics of distributions in the multilevel format (and frankly overall), so I will be the first to admit that I may have missed something useful in equation-heavy resources. Really trying to do the right thing and ensure that our model will allow for reasonable inference, so I appreciate any and all suggestions.